# Mark viewed questions in App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I'm currently browsing through Science Fiction & Fantasy in the Android app. I'm going through question-by-question and each time I back out to the list view, I am struggling to figure out where in the list I am. There's no clear indicator of what has been looked at. I propose simply graying out questions which have been viewed and possibly using an accent color to mark the last question you looked at.